# Arrows between tensor products

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

An arrow between tensor products $A\otimes B\to C\otimes D$ is determined by its components $A\to C$ and $B\to D$. Hence it seems natural to represent such an arrow  by a pair of arrows. **My question is: how to draw such a arrow in tikz-cd?**

The following is my trying. However, it is too complicate and the middle arrow $\otimes$ cannot match the correct boundary of the right-side tensor product.

```
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=0pt]
A\ar[r,phantom,shift right=0.8em,"{f}"]&
Cup\\
\otimes\ar[r,"\otimes"description]&\otimes\\
B\ar[r,phantom,shift left=0.8em,"{g}"]&
Down
\end{tikzcd}
\]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like the idea, but in this case I'd actually like to argue that one may use `tikzmark` instead to annotate an equation. In other words, I am not 100% convinced that one should start out with `tikz-cd` only because of its arrows. After all, LaTeX itself is very good for typesetting equations, and one could just add the arrows with Ti*k*Z rather than designing the full equation.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\[
\left.\begin{array}{c}\tikzmarknode{A}{A}\\ \otimes \\ 
\tikzmarknode{B}{B}\end{array}\!\right\}
\xrightarrow{f\otimes g}
\left\{\!\begin{array}{c}\tikzmarknode{Cup}{\text{Cup}}\\ \otimes \\ 
\tikzmarknode{Down}{\text{Down}}\end{array}\right.
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[-latex,preaction={draw,white,very thick,-}] (A) to[bend left=15] node[midway,above]{$\scriptstyle f$} (Cup);
\draw[-latex,preaction={draw,white,very thick,-}] (B)  to[bend right=15] node[midway,below]{$\scriptstyle g$} (Down);
\end{tikzpicture}

\[
\left.\begin{array}{c}\tikzmarknode{A'}{A}\\ \otimes \\ 
\tikzmarknode{B'}{B}\end{array}\!\right\}
\xrightarrow{f\otimes g}
\left\{\!\begin{array}{c}\tikzmarknode{Cup'}{\text{Cup}}\\ \otimes \\ 
\tikzmarknode{Down'}{\text{Down}}\end{array}\right.
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[->,preaction={draw,white,very thick,-}] (A') to
node[midway,above]{$\scriptstyle f$} (Cup');
\draw[->,preaction={draw,white,very thick,-}] (B')  to
node[midway,below]{$\scriptstyle g$} (Down');
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[
    row sep=0pt,
    every matrix/.append style={name=mycd, nodes={text centered, text height=height{"C"},text depth=depth{"p"}, inner ysep=2pt}
        },    
    /tikz/column 2/.append style={nodes={text width=width("Down")}},
    execute at end picture={
        \draw [decorate,decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=5pt}] (mycd-1-1.north east) -- (mycd-3-1.south east);
        \draw [decorate,decoration={calligraphic brace, mirror, amplitude=5pt}] (mycd-1-2.north west) -- (mycd-3-2.south west);
        },
    ]
A\ar[r,"f", shorten=-.1cm]&[2em]\text{Cup}\\
\otimes\ar[r,"f\otimes g", shorten=.3cm]&\otimes\\
B\ar[r,"g"', shorten=-.1cm]&\text{Down}
\end{tikzcd}
\]


\[
\begin{tikzcd}[
    row sep=0pt,
    every matrix/.append style={name=mycd, nodes={text centered, text height=height{"C"},text depth=depth{"p"}, inner ysep=2pt}
        },    
    /tikz/column 2/.append style={nodes={text width=width("Down")}},
    execute at end picture={
        \draw [decorate,decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=5pt}] (mycd-1-1.north east) -- (mycd-3-1.south east);
        \draw [decorate,decoration={calligraphic brace, mirror, amplitude=5pt}] (mycd-1-2.north west) -- (mycd-3-2.south west);
        },
    ]
A\ar[r,"f", shorten=-.1cm, bend left]&[2em]\text{Cup}\\
\otimes\ar[r,"f\otimes g", shorten=.3cm]&\otimes\\
B\ar[r,"g"', , shorten=-.1cm, bend right]&\text{Down}
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]